# How to marquee multiple UILabel and scrolling it when tap

Tags: ios

I think of getting multiple string set from server and put it in array as separate topic (Ex @"Article_1", @"Article_2", @"Article_3", ...) and then make it to `UILabel` then loop marquee them (Like News headline running in you see on TV). And when tap on the marquee label it should stop. It should scroll left or right when drag. When release tap it should continue to marquee again.

I try using `UIViewAnimationBlock` to marquee it but don't know how to pause it mid way and continue animate from there. Further search they suggests I should use `CAKeyframeAnimation` instead

I also try using [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) but have no idea when I have multiple UILabel or text I want to marquee along with scrolling thing.

Can anybody help me?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

MarqueeLabel is a good class.
If you want to scroll multiple labels you just have to declare them as MarqueeLabel class in storyboard.
If you need to scroll multiple string on the same MarqueeLabel, just concatenate your strings and put the resulting string in your MarqueeLabel.